# Exclude non-overlapping ranges on consecutive rows by group

Tags: r, data.table

I have data frame like  following:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Group = c("scaf1", "scaf1", "scaf1", "scaf2", "scaf2", "scaf2", "scaf3", "scaf3", "scaf4", "scaf4"),
                  Start = c(10, 40, 90, 50, 80, 95, 600, 800, 70, 100),
                  End = c(50, 70, 120, 70, 100, 150, 700, 850, 100, 145))

df1
# group  start  End
# scaf1  10     50
# scaf1  40     70 
# scaf1  90     120
# scaf2  50     70
# scaf2  80     100
# scaf2  95     150
# scaf3  600    700
# scaf3  800    850
# scaf4  70     100
# scaf4  100    145
```

I would like compare the ranges of each row within group and keep only those ranges which are overlapping.

For an example, in group `scaf1`, in the second row the value of `start` is `40` which is within the range of previous range `Start = 10; End = 50`. Hence, both rows are retained.

Whereas the `Start` of the third row `90` in `scaf1` is *not* within the range of previous row (`Start = 40,  End = 70`). So I expect the following output:

```
group  start  End
scaf1  10     50
scaf1  40     70 
scaf2  80     100
scaf2  95     150
scaf4  70     100
scaf4  100    145
```

I tried following command but it failed:

```
setDT(df1)[ , .((start[2] < End[1])[-.N], by = group]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check your expected output.  May be it needs some correction  Why is 50 70 on scaf2 not in the output where as the 10 50 1st row is there

Comment: As akrun already commented, your output seems to be broken. But you can try this: `unlist(lapply(split(df1, df1$Group), function(x) c(TRUE, sapply(1:(length(x$Start)-1), function(y) x$Start[y+1] < x$End[y]))))`

Comment: What happend to this row? `scaf2  50     70` and `scaf3`?

Comment: Maybe `df1 %>% group_by(Group) %>% filter((Start >= lag(Start) & Start <= lag(End)) | row_number() == 1)` ?

Comment: Try `setDT(df1)[df1[, .I[(Start >= shift(Start, fill=0) & Start <= shift(End, fill=0))|seq_len(.N)==1], Group]$V1]`

Comment: @akrun @Jimbou in case of `scaf2 50 70` the consecutive `Start 80` is not within the range of its previous entry `Start 50 and End 70`, so they are ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
df1=data.frame(Group=c("scaf1","scaf1","scaf1","scaf2","scaf2","scaf2","scaf3","scaf3","scaf4","scaf4"),Start=c(10,40,90,50,80,95,600,800,70,100),End=c(50,70,120,70,100,150,700,850,100,145))

df1$filter = F

for(k in 2:nrow(df1)){
    if(df1$Group[k]==df1$Group[k-1] && df1$Start[k]<=df1$End[k-1]){
        df1$filter[k-1]=T
        df1$filter[k]=T
    }
}

df2 = df1[df1$filter==T,]
df2$filter = NULL
```

This is not a vectorized solution, but works as intended.

Result:

```
> df2
   Group Start End
1  scaf1    10  50
2  scaf1    40  70
5  scaf2    80 100
6  scaf2    95 150
9  scaf4    70 100
10 scaf4   100 145
```

Answer (score 0):

A different way to get your output would be to use ranges as defined by the GenomicRanges package.

```
library(GenomicRanges)
# create a GRanges object
df1_gr <- GRanges(df1$Group, IRanges(df1$Start, df1$End))
# find the overlaps
gr <- as.data.frame(findOverlaps(df1_gr))
# remove self-overlapping
gr <- gr[gr$queryHits != gr$subjectHits,]
# final dataset
df1[ gr$queryHits, ]
Group Start End
1: scaf1    10  50
2: scaf1    40  70
3: scaf2    80 100
4: scaf2    95 150
5: scaf4    70 100
6: scaf4   100 145
```